# IIS: Unable to load DLL "<dllName>": The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: iis, dll, installation, pinvoke

I have an application that uses .Net remoting. The remotable calls our unmanaged dll that is a client to a Versant database. The previous release of our app communicated with an earlier release of Versant in exactly the same way. We now have 2 different dlls to communicate with the different versions of the database.

The new dll resides in the C:\odin\bin directory, where, in the previous version, the unmanaged dll resided and it worked fine (in other words, it's the same structure). At first we got SxS errors because it was built debug. That worked fine on the development systems, but on a production system, not so much.

Solved that problem and now we get a simple

> Unable to load DLL 'uInfinityDbx.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

error. But it's there! The path is good (points to the directory where it lives.

I'm out of ideas on things to check. Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The DLL file is present, but maybe one of its dependencies is missing. Try loading the DLL in a tool like [Depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to point out dependency problems.